# Url of active index with p:steps

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jquery-steps

I'm using `p:steps` as a workflow, it works well except active index doesn't have an URL attach

xhtml:

```
<p:fieldset legend="Etape" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500" style="height:110px;">
    <p:steps model="#{etapeModel.model}" activeIndex="#{besoin.etape.code}" 
    styleClass="custom" readonly="false" />
</p:fieldset>
```

java code:

```
public EtapeModel(){
    model = new DefaultMenuModel();
    Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    selected = BesoinService.get(Integer.parseInt(params.get("id")));

    for(Etape e : Etape.values()){
        DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem(e.getLibelle());
        item.setUrl("besoinForm.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&i=1&id="+selected.getId()+"&etape="+e.getCode());
        item.setId("etape"+e.getCode());
        model.addElement(item);
    }
}
```

I understand this behaviour, but what possibilities I have to attach an url on active index ?

Mojarra 2.2.0 and Primefaces 5.3

Comment: Need bookmarkable URLs while using other components as well like `<p:dataTable>`, `<p:dataList>`, `<p:dataGrid>` etc. Consult the PrimeFaces team to include such features in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use this component anymore, but best solution I found is to write a custom component based on Steps, a good example here

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/primefaces/extending-primefaces-components

By extending Steps and StepsRenderer using [this source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.primefaces/primefaces/5.2/org/primefaces/component/steps/StepsRenderer.java) and modify the way attribute "href" is write (and "class" too for thing like cursor:hover)